# XHTML/CSS: Why does Firefox mess up my horizontal tab menu?

Tags: css, menu, tabs

[Problem page](http://www.antisit.com)

[Stylesheet](http://www.antisit.com/styles.css)

Any idea how to make this work in Firefox?  (It appears as if the right tab image is being pushed below the link, as if there weren't enough room for it within the anchor element.

Also, the reason that I'm using two  tags is that I prefer using less image data to having neater code.  If you have any suggestions for a better way, let me know.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Do you mean the vertical line appearing to the right of the links on hover?

Comment: It appears not to work in Chrome, either.

Comment: Alex: Yes
Software Monkey: It worked in Chrome for me

Comment: background-repeat? overflow? height? display: block?

Comment: What are the two internal span tags for inside your anchor?

Comment: @steve_c: i'd assume they are for the rounded edges of the hover effect ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this markup:

```
<a href="http://www.antisit.com/articles">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <span class="right"></span>
  Articles
</a>
```

Seems to work fine in Firefox with firebug although I haven't tried anywhere else.
Unfortunately, order shouldn't matter but it does sometimes. :(